# I can't install Android Studio on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit due to error

Tags: 16.04, android, android-studio

Error message in the terminal and the cursor starts blinking and it hangs:

[image: Error message in the terminal and the cursor starts blinking and it hangs]

This is the above error I get after using the following commands in the terminal. Moreover the terminal doesn't work after this.

Code which I use to install android studio:

[image: Code which i use to install android studio]

Comment: Please refrain from posting screenshots of text. You can just copy and paste the text in your question directly.

Comment: Download Android-Studio from here: https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Answer (score 0):

It's the first time I see these intructions to install Android Studio on Ubuntu.

I recommend to use official `Android` page, section `Tools` to download directly newest Android Studio 2.2: http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/android-studio-2-2-stable

Unzip downloaded archive, then using terminal go to unpacked directory, and run

`./bin/studio.sh` file

If you see welcome screen, go to `Configure -> Create Desktop Shortcut` to have an Android Studio launcher in Apps menu.

Hope it will help